# mysql - create event and load data infile to Server automatically

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I need to know if it's possible to Create an Event in `MySQL` with its code statement using Load Data In file syntax.

Here's my current situation.

1. I can get the database (`MS Access`) using `PHP` from a Local Biometric Database.
2. I have updated the database in my Local Database Server which is `MySQL` now.
3. I can update my target Online Database Server via Exporting it first then Importing the database in the Online Database Server.

> My Main Question is how I can manage this without any user interaction
>   such as `MySQL` Event Features?

I am trying to upload a data from my PC (Local server) into our Domain (Web Server)

Comment: Isn't the Mysql Event not without user interaction? It acts as a kind of Cronjob

Comment: Do you have access to `mysqldump` on the server?

Comment: But from the question the locations of the databases is not completly clear to me: Access is somewhere at your office? As is a Mysql database and your PHP. And the target is a database somewhere out there on the internet?

Comment: You can user CURL for posting data on your domain from local and get data on your domain and insert it in database, and call the CURL repetitively or set the cronjob for that.

Comment: @mulquin the server is not fully access to us and its not possible to use mysqldump in the console itself.

Comment: @IvoP The main database is at our office and that database should be transferred in the server thru online without any user interaction. I know MYSQL Event can do that but i think i will need to use a 3rd party app in my PC (local server) that has the main database and be transferred using FTP (VB.NET) then when it success i'll try to use the MySQL event with its Load INFILE syntax. I don't know yet the outcome but i think i can help.

I thought if the server using the event can look here at my office the main database to be Load INFILE but i think also it's not possible yet?

Comment: Anything is possible, but it might require a lot of open ports and rights. For starters, it would be nice if the target mysql database can be reached from the ip address of your office

Comment: I'll try to share later on what i did here so everyone can see the results of my work. Thanks :D

Answer (score -1):

Already done this guys, What i did is I've built a local application to my local server at our office then that application is doing a FTP service to upload the updated database from our Local Biometric Database into the online web server.

Once all this is done, I've created a php script which will load the .SQL file using a Cron Job. You all know cron job are time scheduled events for controlling scripts and doing other linux command.

I'll share my code of php file so everyone who encounter this can use this in the future.

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Taipei');
    $CurTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

    if(!$link){
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysqli_error());
    } 

    //Select database
    $db = mysqli_select_db($link,DB_DATABASE);

    if(!$db){
        //Do auto download of database in the Server automatically
        if(file_exists('Database/'.DB_DATABASE.'.sql')){
            mysqli_query($link,"CREATE DATABASE ".DB_DATABASE);
            $db = mysqli_select_db($link,DB_DATABASE);
            $readContent = file_get_contents("Database/".DB_DATABASE.".sql");
            $res = mysqli_multi_query($link,$readContent) or die(mysqli_error($link));
            mysqli_close($link);
        } else {
        die("Unable to select database, Please call your system administrator. Thank you.");    
        }
    }

    function Reload_Database($DBLink){
        if(file_exists($DBLink)){
            //mysqli_query($link,"DROP DATABASE ".DB_DATABASE);
            //mysqli_query($link,"CREATE DATABASE ".DB_DATABASE);
            $link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            $db = mysqli_select_db($link,DB_DATABASE);
            $readContent = file_get_contents($DBLink);
            $res = mysqli_multi_query($link,$readContent) or die(mysqli_error($link));
            mysqli_close($link);
            return 'Database Reloaded';
        } else {
            die("Unable to reload database, Please call your system administrator. Thank you.");    
        }
    }

echo Reload_Database('../employee/database/'.DB_DATABASE.'.sql');
```

This is basic script that will reload the database of the uploaded database given from my local application.

From here the cron job will do its part. Expect that my local application is also a service that will just do the uploading of the updated database of the Local Biometric Database.